# Utilizar el metodo POST en ReSTful en eclipse usando Widfly

Tags: java, rest, post, http

tengo un problema con utilizarl el metodo POST en el siguiente codigo.

Donde Utilizo el IDE Eclipse Oxygen, con el servidor Widfly 10 y utilizando ReSTful para el protocolo.

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class doLogin {
    private String cuenta;
    private String pass;

    public doLogin() {
        System.out.println("***************Donde estoy en el constructor");

        this.cuenta = "Anfitrion";

    }

    public String getCuenta() {
        return cuenta;
    }

    public void setCuenta(String cuenta) {
        this.cuenta = cuenta;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public void wc() {
        try {
            Client cliente = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            Score f = cliente.target("http://localhost:8080/PrimerReSTful/rest/HelloWorld/sayHelloPst")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(Score.class);
            System.out.println(f.getWins());
            System.out.println(f.getLooses());
            System.out.println(f.getTies());
            System.out.println(f.getMetodo());

            System.out.println("Donde estoy: wc");
            System.out.println("Cuenta:" + cuenta + "   " + "Password:" + pass);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }

}
```

Donde toma el metodo POST de la siguiente clase:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldService {

     @GET
     @Path("/sayHello")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public String sayHello() {
     String wins = "aaaa", looses = "0000", ties = "EEEE",metodo="Get";

     String pattern = "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"looses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\",\"metodo\":\"%s\"}";
     return String.format(pattern, wins, looses, ties, metodo);
     }

    @POST
    @Path("/sayHelloPst")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sayHelloPst() {
        String wins = "aaaa", looses = "0000", ties = "EEE", metodo="Post", Pt="";

        String pattern = "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"looses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\",\"metodo\":\"%s\"}";
        Pt = String.format(pattern, wins, looses, ties, metodo);
        return Response.ok(Pt).build();
    }

}
```

Cuando utilizo el metodo GET no surge ningun problema, sin embargo, al querer usa POST me salta el error:

> javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme y muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Comment: ¿? En el código mostrado estás haciendo GET de la URL del método POST.

Comment: Recuerda para que el wildfly funcione debes eliminar el tomcat embebido y agregar la dependencia de undertow para trabajar con wildfly server

Comment: Gracias, no era por ahi el error, si estaba bien todo con el wildfly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando spring + restful + wildfly te dejo un ejemplo de como hacer para que la clase funcione correctamente.

```
// Configuracion de la clase para procesar peticiones Restful
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MicroServiceController {
// Ejemplo de inversion de control con anotaciones para instanciar la clase de interes.
@Autowired
private UsuariosService usuariosService;

// Ejemplo del metodo get
@GetMapping("/autenticacion/{nombreUsuario}")   
public ResponseEntity<String> procesoAutenticacion(@PathVariable(value = "nombreUsuario") String nombreUsuario) {
    ResponseEntity<String> reHttp = null;
    Optional<Tokens> tokenSpring = null;

    // regresando el tokenUsuario
    final Optional<Usuarios> tokenUsuario = usuariosService.listarLosUsuarios().stream()
                                        .filter(s -> s.getUsuario().equalsIgnoreCase(nombreUsuario) || //Si es el mismo nombre de usuario
                                                     s.getTelefono().equalsIgnoreCase(nombreUsuario) || // o es el mismo telefono
                                                     s.getCorreo().equalsIgnoreCase(nombreUsuario)) // o es el mismo correo
                                        .findFirst();

    // regresando el tokenSpring
    if(tokenUsuario.isPresent()) { // Si existe el token de usuario
     tokenSpring = tokensService.listarTokens().stream()
                                .filter(s -> s.getUsuarios().getTokenUsuario().equalsIgnoreCase(tokenUsuario.get().getTokenUsuario()))
                                .findFirst();
    }



    if(tokenUsuario.isPresent() && tokenSpring.isPresent()) { // Si existen los elementos de interes.
        reHttp = ResponseEntity
                    .ok("{\"Usuario\":\""+tokenUsuario.get().getTokenUsuario()+"\" , \"tokenSpring\":\""+tokenSpring.get().getTokenSpring()+"\"}");

    }else {
        reHttp = ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                    .body("{\"Usuario\":\"Error\" , \"tokenSpring\":\"Error\"}");
    }

    return reHttp;

}

// ejemplo del metodo post
@PostMapping("/estilista/servicios/historicos")
public ResponseEntity< List<Servicios> > serviciosHistoricos(@RequestBody ServiciosHoyFormato formato) {
    List<Servicios> sHistoricos = null;

    ResponseEntity< List<Servicios> > reHttp = null;

    // Listando todos los servicios segun local y usuario
    sHistoricos = serviciosService.listarServicios()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(s -> 
                                    s.getLocales().getIdLocal() == formato.getIdLocal() && // Comparando el id del local
                                    s.getUsuarios().getTokenUsuario().equalsIgnoreCase(formato.getTokenUsuario()) // Comparando token del Usuario
                                    )
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if(sHistoricos == null || sHistoricos.isEmpty()) { // No existen locales para este usuario
                reHttp = ResponseEntity
                        .status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
                        .body(sHistoricos);
    }else {
                reHttp = ResponseEntity
                        .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .body(sHistoricos);
    }

    return reHttp;
}
```

Comment: Gracias! me fue de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus respuestas, lo pude solucionar usando un objeto response del lado de la aplicacion que llama al webservice

webTarget = cliente.target("URL del servicio ReST").path("/dologin");
             invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);

```
         response = webTarget.request().post( Entity.form(form));
```